# angular.element dom manipulationm inside app.run

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to make dom manipulation on a .run function in AngularJS? Somnething like:

app.run(function(){
        angular.element("#id").css("background-color", "blue");
   })

I've tried running it myself. It didn't work but maybe someone knows an alternative way of doing it inside run.

**PS.**

I am aware that this can be done in a controller but I am trying to achieve this in a run function

Comment: Both approaches are completely wrong. Use a directive. DOM code is never put in controllers or run blocks and most likely the element doesn't exist when either of them are fired

Comment: This is definitely an XY question.  Anytime you say "I am aware this can be done some way but I really want to do it this way instead", you are in that territory.  You should explain the actual result you want, instead of trying to ask why your solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Claies I am actually asking if what I want to do is achievable

Comment: it's not achievable the way you describe it, but the point is you aren't describing why you think you need to do it this way.  If you were to present the actual problem, then we can work on coming up with a solution that achieves what you want;  "I want to do this in `.run`" isn't a problem, it's what you decided was going to be necessary to achieve your result, probably because there is some portion of angular setup and initialization that you aren't fully aware of.

Comment: @Claies  Well that's the answer that I am looking for "it's not". There are many ways to solve my issue. I am just asking if it can be done using .run

Answer (score 0):

CSS selector wont work in jQlite, angular.element(**"#id"**).

> Note: Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag
>   name / CSS selector. For lookups by tag name, try instead
>   angular.element(document).find(...) or $document.find(), or use the
>   standard DOM APIs, e.g. document.querySelectorAll()

This is an excerpt from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

If you are using JQuery, then check if the #id element is loaded in DOM by the time run block is executed.

Comment: Actually you can. You have to put the jquery library first before the angular to achieve that